# Deep Learning Approaches for Aggregating Data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, feature-engineering

I am looking for an automatic way of aggregating data to derive meaning features. For example, I have a table. It contains multiple customers. Each customer is associated with multiple loans. Each loan is associated with multiple payments. So the table contains these three columns: customer, loan and payment. If I want to get something like each customer's last loan's average payment. I need to first aggregate payment to loan level to get "average" payment. Then need to aggregate loan to customer level to figure out "last" loan. Since I am looking for an automatic way of doing so, a simple approach would be to use a **rule-based** approach. It goes like this: if a table contains customer, loan, payment, then I will do the above aggregation to get each customer's last loan's average payment. Since I intend to do this sort of **meaningful** aggregation for all possible columns, I need to implement a lot of rules to do so. I see deep learning can do some very intelligent things for some applications. I wonder if it is possible to use deep learning to come up with an intelligent way to do aggregation.

Comment: Seems like writing a SQL query would be easier

Comment: Using SQL query means users need to intervene to generate desired features, so it is a rule-based approach. I am looking for an automatic system which once knows, e.g. customer, loan, payment is present in the table, I will generate features like each customer's last loan's average payment. Another example is that suppose a table contains customer, trip, expense, features like each customer's most expensive trip's total expense.

Comment: I stand by my comment. Trying to get machine learning to write your SQL for you, and understand what a "meaingful" feature is as opposed to a "not meaningful" feature is, and extrapolate to "all meaningful features" and exclude all "not meaningful features" is way harder than just writing SQL, possibly using some rudimentary tools to substitute data elements like different `user_id`s etc.

Comment: Can you name a specific ML/DL technique for write SQL for this task? Sounds like intention detection and slot filling can fit the bill.

Comment: I'm saying that I don't think your task is easily done *at all*. At best, you can use an LSTM to generate code from other code examples: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ But I don't think this achieves anything that's as specific as what you want, because it doesn't make code that *does what you specifically want*, which is why I think you should really be focusing on how to abstract using pre-written SQL to suit your needs.